# What's the radius of convergence of this power series?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C},\ c \notin \mathbb{Z}^-\cup \{0\}$, define $s_0=1$ and:
$$s_n = \frac{1}{n!}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(a+k-1)(b+k-1)}{c+k-1},\ \forall n\geq1$$

What's the radius of convergence $\rho$ of the power series S=$\sum_{n\geq 0} s_nX^n?$

If $\{a,b\}\cap (\mathbb{Z}^-\cup\{0\})\neq \emptyset$ then trivially $\rho=+\infty$. My problem is with the other case; the only thing that came to my mind was the ratio test, but that didn't work.

This is exercise number 6 from chapter 1 of Henri Cartan's *Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions of One or Several Complex Variables*.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2665575/123905

Comment: Why do you say the ratio test doesn't work?  It should.